# How To Remove Product Title from Breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, breadcrumbs

As the majority of people visit my Magento 1 site on a smartphone, I feel the breadcrumb is taking up to much screen real estate. As my product titles are quite long, the breadcrumb is often displayed on 2-3 lines on mobile.

On magento 1, the standard breadcrumb layout is like this:

> Home - category 1 - category 2 - product title

I would like to change it to only:

> Home - category 1 - category 2

Is there an efficient way to do this? I've tried it by tweaking CSS (`display: none`), but it's not possible to only hide the product title part of the breadcrumbs.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly Magento has no built-in method to remove breadcrubs.

I'd recommened this free extension: https://github.com/netz98/N98_LayoutHelper

It adds some usefull features to modify layout and one of them is to remove breadcrumbs.

> app/design/frontend/your/theme/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="removeCrumb"><name>product</name></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```